# ClickOnce deployment, application not running on startup when server not ready

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

I have a application using ClickOnce deployment, run from a server. A shortcut of the .appref-ms file is placed in the user's startup folder, and MOST of the time this works fine, it connects to the server and the requirements (updates) are checked and then the app runs.

However, sometimes it tries to connect/verify but fails, gives no error message and just doesn't launch the application. I am assuming this is because the server is not yet ready. Is there any way to make the clickonce application wait until it can connect? (Or try 3 times for example)

Comment: First thing to do is to verify that the issue is actually with ClickOnce. Add some logging to your app startup code and check the logs when you see the failure to ensure that your app code was never reached

Comment: Log shows no errors. Have found people with similar problems using Kensington mouse drivers but have none installed. Any other ideas?

Comment: Does this mean that your application starts always?

Comment: When the .appref-ms file is in the users startup folder, it will startup. However sometimes it fails to launch after doing its "verifying requirements" phase